# (Is it just me, or....) Clicking "Tools" on the menu bar takes me to the "Migrated" questions page

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I was reviewing posts today and when I went to look at the *Tools* page, it took me to the *Migrated questions* page instead. Is anybody else being redirected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you go Review-> Tools, it loads the last Tools page you used.  If you then click Stats, Close, Delete, or Flags, then the next time you to Review-> Tools, you'll end up on that page instead of Migrated.

Comment: Implicit but important in this is that "Migrated questions" is one of the 10k tools.

Comment: Facepalm. Thanks.